# How to plot a Beveridge Curve in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

Suppose the two time series:

```
myvector<-rnorm(10,1,72)
myvector1<-rnorm(5,1,72)
myts <- ts(myvector, start=c(2009, 1), end=c(2014, 12), frequency=12) 
myts1 <- ts(myvector1, start=c(2009, 1), end=c(2014, 12), frequency=12)
```

How can i create a plot like the one in this image where each of the variable in at  the axis of the plot, and each dot represents the day (quarter, or year). This plot is also known as a Beveridge curve plot. Any suggestions are highly welcome.

[image: The desired plot]

Comment: The plot was found on the internet from a google search. Code or packages that are required were not to be found. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ggplot, something like this:

```
   library(ggplot2)     
   df <- as.data.frame(cbind(myts, myts1))

   ggplot(data=df)+
   geom_line(data=df, aes(x=myts, y=myts1, group=1), linetype = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The plot for the Beveridge curve is a scatter plot, where a line connects the sequential points, representing the job vacancy rate and the unemployment rate at a period. Using different line colours helps distinguish between movements along the curve, reflecting changes in labour market tightness and shifts in the curve closer to or further from the origin, representing changes in labour market efficiency. You can combine geom_point and geom_path with ggplot to make this distinction. If you use geom_line instead of geom_path, the line may pass through points closer in space rather than time, misrepresenting the information. I limited the replicable data to two periods, but you should see they closely match the original image from the BLS.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
    
  Month <- format(c('2007-12-01','2008-01-01','2008-02-01','2008-03-01','2008-04-01','2008-05-01','2008-06-01','2008-07-01','2008-08-01','2008-09-01','2008-10-01','2008-11-01','2008-12-01','2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2009-03-01','2009-04-01','2009-05-01','2009-06-01','2020-05-01','2020-06-01','2020-07-01','2020-08-01','2020-09-01','2020-10-01','2020-11-01','2020-12-01','2021-01-01','2021-02-01','2021-03-01','2021-04-01','2021-05-01','2021-06-01','2021-07-01','2021-08-01','2021-09-01','2021-10-01','2021-11-01'), format="%Y-%b-%d")
  
  Job.openings.rate <- c(3.2,3.2,3,3,2.8,3,2.7,2.7,2.6,2.3,2.4,2.3,2.3,2,2.1,1.9,1.7,1.9,1.9,3.9,4.2,4.6,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.5,4.5,4.7,5,5.4,6,6.1,6.5,7,6.7,6.7,7,6.8)
  
  Unemployment.rate <- c(5,5,4.9,5.1,5,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.1,6.1,6.5,6.8,7.3,7.8,8.3,8.7,9,9.4,9.5, 13.3,11.1,10.2,8.4,7.8,6.9,6.7,6.7,6.3,6.2,6,6.1,5.8,5.9,5.4,5.2,4.8,4.6,4.2)
  
dat <- data.frame(Month,Job.openings.rate,Unemployment.rate)
  dat$Month <- as.Date(dat$Month, origin = "1899-12-30")
  dat$Month <- strptime(dat$Month, "%Y-%m-%d")
  
  dat <- dat %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(period = case_when(
                                     Month>=ymd('2007-12-01') & Month<ymd('2009-07-01') ~  1,
                                     Month>=ymd('2020-05-01') & Month<=ymd('2021-11-01') ~  2))
  
  dat$period <- factor(dat$period, levels=c(1,2))
  
  cbp2 <- c( "orange", "black")
  names <- c("1" = "Dec 2007 to Jun 2009", 
             "2" = "May 2020 to Nov 2021")
  
bc <-  dat %>% ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x=Unemployment.rate, y=Job.openings.rate, group=period, colour=period)) + 
    geom_path(aes(x=Unemployment.rate, y=Job.openings.rate, group=period, colour=period)) +
    ggtitle("The Beveridge Curve (job openings rate vs. unemployment rate), seasonally adjusted") +
    scale_color_manual(values = cbp2, labels=names) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = cbp2, labels=names) +
    xlab("Unemployment rate") +
    ylab("Job openings rate") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.position = c(.8, .75)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=.5))
    theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title.align = "1", legend.title = element_text("Legend"))
```

[image]

The data and original image below are from the BLS, which updates the image and data monthly. https://www.bls.gov/charts/job-openings-and-labor-turnover/job-openings-unemployment-beveridge-curve.htm

[image]